# IIS 6.0 website Creation differences

Tags: configuration, iis-6

i would like to know under what circumstances do the menus in the below images appear?[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to to this, for this to work the directory must be in wwwRoot, if you dont find it you must refresh until it appears.